# iterate through instances of a class inside itself

Tags: c#, static, static-members

(I didn't create this, but i must work with this)

```
class Person{

  public string Name {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public static Person P1 = new Person("name1");
  public static Person A1 = new Person("aName1");
  public static Person ZX1 = new Person("NameZX");
  public static Person P2 = new Person("name2");
  .
  .
  public static Person P20 = new Person("name20");    
}
```

I need to iterate through all of these instances, i think it involves reflection but i'm not sure exactly how to.

@Selman22, thanks, now i must loop through these persons

```
forach(var p in persons)
{
}
```

However `p` is a `FieldInfo` object, how do i change it back to a `Person` (casting isn't working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your fields using `Reflection` like this:

```
var persons = typeof(Person)
             .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
             .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("P"));
```

Or:

```
var persons = typeof(Person)
              .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
              .Where(x => x.GetValue(null) is Person);

foreach(var p in persons)
{
    var currentPerson = p.GetValue(null) as Person;
    ...
}
```

Comment: hey, is there any way to differentiate the instances from the properties, sorry they don't all start with 'P', ill edit my question.

Comment: @heyNow then try the second solution.btw, you need to differentiate the properties and fields

Comment: hey, ive edit my question, i must loop through these now

Comment: @heyNow use the `GetValue` method of `FieldInfo` class.

Comment: I think it is better to filter fields using type.
`Person[] persons = typeof(Person).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Person)).Select(f => (Person)f.GetValue(null)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You could just put them all in array and then do it:

```
var people = new[]
{
    Person1,
    Person2,
    ...
    Person20
};

foreach (var person in people)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders I didn't downvote.. But I would guess they come from the fact that this answer does not answer the question. The question starts out by saying that he _must_ work with the code provided. To me this means that he is not allowed to change the code.

Comment: @MAV: then I would say that was a mis-reading of the question, since it said iterate through those members _inside of the class_. The worst I could say about this answer is that it should be `P1`, `P2`, not `Person1`, `Person2`.

Comment: This answer requires zero code changes to the original class. The fields are public so can be put into an array by some other code.

Comment: hey, (didn't downvote) i have more than 300 of these `Person1`, etc.. i thought of looping instead of creating array. I don't know who wrote it like that in the library i use but that's what i must work with